# wso2 identity server manage JDBCUserStore

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I used wso2 identity server with multi JDBCUserStore.

Is it possible to define a user who will only be able to manage the users of a single user JDBCUserStore.

Comment: Are you trying to manage users of an organization in one user store? I hope you have a requirement of organization management, haven't you.